# How to scroll back to the text which is overflowed due to screen size in TextView?

Tags: android, scroll, textview, scrollview, horizontal-scrolling

Half of my day consumed just because of this question, still unsolved. So here I am, my question is simple.
I am using a `TextView`.
XMl code:

```
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:id="@+id/text_view1"/>
```

I set the gravity to the right as it is my requirement. I am using buttons to set text in this `texview`. Each press of a button appends a text to the existing one.
due to `screensize` this text will overflow, only the beginning of the whole string is displayed. For displaying latest text from a button press, I did this

```
 mText.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
 mText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

now am able to display what text is set to the `textview` on each `button` press. but how could I able to see the whole text ie how to scroll back to the beginning of text view's text???

Please don't suggest any answer related to vertical scrolling or automatic scrolling.
Help me out, guys... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you `xml` put:

```
android:scrollbars = "horizontal"
```

And then in your `Java` use:

```
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```